# Angular 6 - RouterLink navigates but not changing URL

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-router, routelink

app.component.html

```
<nav>
 <a routerLink="/dashboard"></a>
 <a routerLink="/reports"></a>
<nav>
<main role="main" class="page-container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ReportsComponent } from './reports/reports.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'reports', component: ReportsComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ReportsComponent } from './reports/reports.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ReportsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

With the above code, I see that on click of the nav links, am able to navigate to the corresponding component but for some reason, URL is not getting updated.

Not sure if am missing something pretty basic here. Please help.

Comment: it's working as expected, BTW where are you using `<router-outlet>`? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nmv6bh

Comment: Your code seem to have no issues. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ru2wbj

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal - Updated the post with the usage of <router-outlet>. If it is working as expected, what should i do to get the URL changed?

Comment: @balachanderj what do you mean by `to get the URL changed`? it's already getting changed.

Comment: Which URL are you trying to check? Browser URL? It just works fine.

Comment: Only difference between the code that i pasted here and the actual code is that I have an AngularJS component that i use calling upgrade.bootstrap in app.module.ts. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @RafaelAndrade - Am using chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you are running hybrid app(with upgrade module) add useHash to router config

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, enableTracing: true })],
```

Comment: Could I trouble you to explain what this does exactly, and why it is necessary?

Comment: "Beware programming by coincidence"!