# Angular 8 - router navigates to component but does not change URL

Tags: angular, angular-router

I've already looked through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50649478/angular-6-routerlink-navigates-but-not-changing-url) post to add `{useHash: true}` but it did not fix my problem. I am able to navigate to the component but the URL never changes. It stays at localhost:4211 where it's hosted. I also am not able to manually type the URL like `localhost:4211/atm` to route to that component. I believe there's a disconnect between the URL and router.

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "", 
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: "full"
  },
  {
    path: "home", 
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: "atm", 
    component: AtmFormPageComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" >Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/atm" >atm</a>
      </li>
```

I have the Router module imported and there are no errors in console or network.

Comment: It appears you are using bootstrap. Are you sure that you've properly imported the library into your project?

Comment: @Z.Bagley Yes I've imported it correctly using the styles.css file

Comment: Are you using a router-outlet, if so can we see parent & child routes

Comment: can you reproduce this issue in stackblitz.com. It may easy to resolve your issue.

Comment: You are likely missing the javascript files for bootstrap. Import those via your scripts section in your **angular.json**